# R grep search patterns in multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame like as follows:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       B       C
D       E       F
G       H       I
```

I am trying to keep lines matching 'B' in 'Col2' OR F in 'Col3', in order to get:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       B       C
D       E       F
```

I tried:

```
data[(grep("B",data$Col2) || grep("F",data$Col3)), ]
```

but it returns the entire data frame.

NOTE: it works when calling the 2 grep one at a time.

Comment: You should read about the difference between | and ||, for example [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/logical-operators-in-r/)

Comment: @HubertL: I was not aware of that. Useful ref.

Comment: `help(Logic)` is a useful reference as well.  It's great how none of the answers address what the actual issue in your code was (`|` vs. `||`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with(df1, df1[ Col2 == 'B' | Col3 == 'F',])
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1    A    B    C
# 2    D    E    F
```

Using `grepl`

```
with(df1, df1[ grepl( 'B', Col2) | grepl( 'F', Col3), ])
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1    A    B    C
# 2    D    E    F
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "D", "G"), Col2 = c("B", "E", "H"
), Col3 = c("C", "F", "I")), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6):

Or using a single `grepl` after `paste`ing the columns

```
df1[with(df1, grepl("B|F", paste(Col2, Col3))),]
#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1    A    B    C
#2    D    E    F
```

Comment: I am trying to do something quite similar. i.e I want to search if any of the patterns matches in any of the several columns. now I have a series of similarly named columns, say Col1,Col2,......Col10 This code works with `df1[with(df1, grepl("B|F", paste(Col1, Col2,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10))),]` . But is there any way to do without having to write this long list of Column names.  I tried with `paste(paste(cde_diag_colnames,collapse =","))` but that doesn't work

Comment: @TriparnaPoddar you can do `i1 <- Reduce("|", lapply(df1[paste0("Col", 1:10)], function(x) grepl("B|F", x))); df1[i1,]`

Answer (score 0):

The **data.table** package makes this type of operation trivial due to its compact and readable syntax. Here is how you would perform the above using data.table:

```
> df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "D", "G"), Col2 = c("B", "E", "H"
+ ), Col3 = c("C", "F", "I")), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"
+ ), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

> library(data.table)
> DT <- data.table(df1)
> DT
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1:    A    B    C
2:    D    E    F
3:    G    H    I

> DT[Col2 == 'B' | Col3 == 'F']
   Col1 Col2 Col3
1:    A    B    C
2:    D    E    F
>
```

data.table performs its matching operations with **with=TRUE** by default. Note that the matching is much faster if you set keys on the data but that is for another topic.